# Unable to resize to the right if there is a block there with height and width set

Tags: javascript, html, css

When setting a fixed width and height for two squares within a containing square, the resize functionality from the css tag 'resize': 'both'; is able to resize fine to the left but slows down when the left box is resized larger to the right.

For demonstration purposes I have put a code snippet below. If the left square is resized to the left, then the box resizes with ease. But if the left square is resized to the right and encroaches on the right square the resizing slows down and the right block does not get smaller.

I want the functionality to be that if the left block is dragged bigger to the right, that the right block will get smaller.

```css
/* style.css */
.resizable-square {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-square {
    width: 300px; /* Initial width of the container */
    height: 300px; /* Initial height of the container */
    display: flex; /* Use Flexbox for inner squares */
    align-items: center; /* Center inner squares vertically */
    justify-content: space-around; /* Space out inner squares */
    background-color: #90EE90; /* Light green background for container */
}

.inner-square {
    width: 100px; /* Initial width of inner squares */
    height: 100px; /* Initial height of inner squares */
    background-color: #6495ED; /* Light blue background for inner squares */
    margin: 10px; /* Space between inner squares and container border */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Resizable Squares</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="resizable-square container-square">
        <div class="resizable-square inner-square"></div>
        <div class="resizable-square inner-square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet, there are two squares inside one larger one. If you drag the corner of the left square toward the left. There are two dashes at the bottom right of each square that can be clicked and dragged.

Comment: I made a very dumb comment that I removed.. yes it's clear what you meant.